# How to convert PNG binary content to WEBP keeping transparency

Tags: php, webp

How can I convert a png image binary content to webp keeping transparency?

I have:

```php
imagewebp(imagecreatefromstring($binaryContent), $input, $quality);
```

I've tried:

```php
$img = imagecreatefromstring($binaryContent);
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagewebp($img, $input, $quality);
```

but it's not keeping transparency. Any idea?

Comment: PD of [webp image display black background instead of transparency](//stackoverflow.com/q/54477435) ?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @ashimapanjwani - Yes, using Imagick instead of GD